# How do some Qt functions not block?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

When I call QNetworkAccessManager::get() or QNetworkAccessManager::post() or many other methods the program flow continues on after the call and if I want further interaction, like getting what was received from the server, I need to use signals/slots. Do these functions run in their own thread? But the times I have used threads I have had to call something like MyClass::start() which doesn't happen when I call get() or post().

The times I have built a threaded class, the only way to start a function in the class is through MyClass:start() and MyClass::run(). But right now I have a class that has all sorts of functions in it that get called, and these functions should run in the background so that the main application can later receive a signal from those functions.

Hypothetically I'd have something like this

```
class MyClass
{
   public:
     void func1();
     void func2();
};

MyClass::func1()
{
   // move off into other thread
   // do stuff
   emit signal1(data1)
}

MyClass::func2()
{
   // move off into other thread
   // do stuff
   emit signal2(data2)
}
```

I should be able to access MyClass::func1 or func2 directly which would be cumbersome if the only was to access them were through MyClass::start().

I hope this makes sense, I'm more a php person, these things are a bit foreign to me.

**In sum**, I'm looking to have a class, with multiple public functions all of which can be called on their own thread. I think. Maybe I'm on the wrong track.

Comment: Sorry but I can't follow you...tell me if I understand: you want to get() or post() something, and in the meanwhile doing something else(which is reasonable by the way..), without using thread or signal/slot?

Comment: I used get() and post() as examples as functions that seem to run in their own thread, but are not started with a start() function but are called direction. I am wondering how this happens because I want to do the same sort of thing (not literally, but running in a different thread without start()).

Comment: Where is the advantage if you don't call start()/ run() ? It's a liner..

Comment: I assume that Qt uses a different thread for this asynchronous

Comment: one possible answer could be to have `MyClass` in its own thread and use the functions as `public slots` and connect them.

the other thing would be that the `Func(n)()` will call `QtConcurrent::run()` to execute its code

Comment: Can you please rephrase the post? I don't really understand what the question is.